# Android Notifications (HTML5/Hybrid)

Tags: android, html, notifications, node-webkit

I'm in the process of creating an app that has tasks, todo's, calendar events, etc. for android.

However, I have looked for weeks and have not found a way to notify users without knowing Java. I use Intel XDK for development, and it has Push.Mobi stuff.

The thing is though, I can't have my app reliant on a connection to the internet.

The best way to explain my goal is this: Google Calendar and other apps will give you alerts and notifications when a certain time comes. I need to be able to do that, using HTML5 node-webkit.

Is there a way? What is the best way I could go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Notification = Java, is the best way to do it.

After reaf your goal, i think the and repeat the best way, easiest, fastest, and simply way is use Native develpment.
Is Just my opinion and experience.